# Integration of (Phi(x)-Phi(y))^2d(F(x, y)

Tags: normal-distribution, integral, bivariate

How to integrate the following? Thanks

[image]

Comment: This notation is vague: do you mean that $dF(x,y)=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x\partial y}F(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ and the integral is a double integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Yes, that what I mean. Thanks, whuber.